# Vue 3's equivalent to useEffect (React)

Tags: reactjs, state, vuejs3, store, use-effect

This code is working, but I'm new to Vue.js and I can't help but think there's a cleaner way of doing this.

In particular I mean the parts that set the data upon entrance and update (of store state) in case it's the first page you visit (or reload). I have a store that fetches data from the backend when the site loads, but that's probably obvious.

I just feel like I'm repeating myself when calling `this.getTodo();` from both `watch` and `mounted`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Details Page</h2>
    {{ title }}
    {{ content }}
    {{ lastEditTime }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      lastEditTime: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTodo () {
      if (this.$store.state.list.length > 0) {
        const id = this.$route.params.id;
        const todoItem = this.$store.getters.getItem(id);
        Object.assign(this, todoItem);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.list': {
      handler() {
        this.getTodo();
      }
    } 
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getTodo();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `immediate` flag to your watcher. That way it runs on mounted as well as every time the `$store.state.list` changes.

```
  watch: {
    '$store.state.list': {
      handler() {
        this.getTodo();
      },
      immediate: true
    } 
  }
```

Update:

As pointed out by @Thomas, you can also use `watchEffect` : https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect

Comment: Or use https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect

Comment: Just curios, is watchEffect accessible via Options API?

Comment: should be as it is documented in the general area not the composition API

Comment: Thomas's solution is more equivalent because watchEffect can depend on multiple states same as useEffect